How to create conda environment using python built from source that is located in a separate directory
I built python 3.11 from source on a research cluster following the guide in this post.
Now, I would like to create a Conda environment using this python version that is stored in a directory like home/software/python3118
How do I go about doing this?
I have tried doing running the following conda create --name scenicplus /home/software/python3118/bin/python=3.11 but that doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Conda isn't really intended for that - environments should be limited to packaged software, preferably Conda packages, but there is some PyPI support. Be aware if you are doing research that what you're proposing undermines reproducibility. Conda isn't perfect, but a major advantage it provides is getting users away from source compiling, in favor of using canonically compiled versions. That said as a plea to "please reconsider", you could bundle your binary into a custom Conda package, or create a dummy package.

The quickest solution I can think of is to create a file with all the libraries you have

For example

/home/software/python3118/bin/python=3.11 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt


then create the conda environment with the version of python you need

conda create --name scenicplus python=3.11
conda activate scenicplus


And finally install the libraries that you had in the requirements.txt file

pip install -r requirements.txt

